# How would I fill out my employer on the graduate-school application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, job

I need to fill out a short history of my work experience (including volunteer). It’s not very critical for the admissions decision (they will have my CV, which is much more important), but I still need to fill it out. Anyways, I have worked as a research assistant for a professor. I was not employed by the school or the government (although I worked with people form both). My supervisor / professor was the one who paid me. In addition, I had a very similar role on my fourth-year project but was not paid. What would I put down for “employer”?

Comment: Did you volunteer in a research group associated with a university?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai No. I had a supervisor who hired me as his RA. I worked with a team of researchers that were positioned all around the country.

Comment: Who did the RA work for?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai both the school and a branch in the government

Comment: Look, if you're going to want an answer to the question "who is my employer" you're going to need to be a lot less vague. I get you want to be anonymous but you're being too vague to understand.